# Updating Form Controls from Events in another class

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

i'm a very beginer in C # and it's also my first post here so please be nice with me :)

Well, i'm trying to code a litle apps that read a file only if it changed and update the new content  in a richtextbox control in a Windows Form.

So there is my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                string path = @"C:\MyPath\";
                Filecheck NewFileChecker = new Filecheck();
                NewFileChecker.WatchingFile(path, "myFile.txt");
            }
```

And This is my Class FileCheck

```
class Filecheck
{
        public void WatchingFile (string FilePath, string Filter)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Path = FilePath;
            fsw.Filter = Filter;
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            fsw.Changed += OnFileChange;
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }


        private void OnFileChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string line;
            try
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(line);
                        // I WOULD LIKE TO UPDATE A FORM1 RichTextBox from here....
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, i'll would like to update a Windows Form control from where i do the MessageBox method.  Someone have an idea how can i do that ?  Because when i tried to invoke like this :

```
Form1.richTextBoxName.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
Form1.richTextBoxName.Text(line);
}));
```

Well, i get this message: "CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Someone have an idea how can i solve that ?
Thanks

Comment: `Form1` is a class name.  You need to use the *instance* object reference for things like controls.  Begin your research with the **[Application.OpenForms Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.8)**  But almost always you would be better off simply adding a method or property to pass information to the form and let it fiddle with it own internal controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of solutions for your idea, but I help you one case:

> Use `delegate`:

**Step 1**: Create a new delegate with param is 01 `string` , `return type` is `void`, name is `UpdateData`:

```
public delegate void UpdateData(string data);
```

**Step 2**: Declare a `event` in `Filecheck` `class` (`OnUpdateData`) with the `delegate` created:

```
public event UpdateData OnUpdateData;
```

**Step 3**: Raise the event anywhen you want:

```
this.OnUpdateData?.Invoke(line);
```

**Step 4**: In your `main` function, set `OnUpdateData` by:

```
Filecheck NewFileChecker = new Filecheck();
NewFileChecker.OnUpdateData += (d => MessageBox.Show(d));
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public delegate void UpdateData(string data);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string path = @"C:\MyPath\";
            Filecheck NewFileChecker = new Filecheck();
            NewFileChecker.OnUpdateData += (d => MessageBox.Show(d));
            NewFileChecker.WatchingFile(path, "myFile.txt");
        }
    }
    class Filecheck
    {
        public event UpdateData OnUpdateData;
        public void WatchingFile(string FilePath, string Filter)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Path = FilePath;
            fsw.Filter = Filter;
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            fsw.Changed += OnFileChange;
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }


        private void OnFileChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            string line;
            try
            {
                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(line);
                        // I WOULD LIKE TO UPDATE A FORM1 RichTextBox from here....
                        this.OnUpdateData?.Invoke(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is my solution. If you apply it to your real project, maybe you have to use MethodInvoke

Comment: Yes, That's work for my idea. but I made some modifications to get this working in my project...  Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! That's work very well in my project for my idea Nguyen Van Thanh.  But I made some modifications to get this working if it can help anothers..  Thank you very much for your input.

In the main Class:

```
public Form1()
{
    string path = @"C:\MyPath\";            
    Filecheck NewFileChecker = new Filecheck();
    NewFileChecker.OnUpdateData += (d => UpdateRTBoxJournal(d));
    NewFileChecker.WatchingFile(path, "myFile.txt");
}

public void UpdateRTBoxJournal(string line)
{
    richTextBoxName.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
    richTextBoxName.Text = line;
    }));
}
```

And finally in the other class in another file...

```
public delegate void UpdateData(string data);
class Filecheck
{
    public event UpdateData OnUpdateData;
    public void WatchingFile (string FilePath, string Filter)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fsw.Path = FilePath;
        fsw.Filter = Filter;
        fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        fsw.Changed += OnFileChange;
        fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnFileChange(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string line;
        try
        {
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    this.OnUpdateData?.Invoke(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreur s'est produite." + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again for your anwser.

Comment: You can use only: `NewFileChecker.OnUpdateData += UpdateRTBoxJournal;`

Answer (score 0):

1. The Form1 class needs to be new when you try to use it.
2. If you want to use the Form1 by your function, you can set the Form1 to Static Type.

Comment: I think you are trying to help the person posting the question understand the difference between an instance of the class (created using new Form1()) and the class itself. I think your answer would be more helpful if you stated that:

You are trying to use the class as if it were an instance of the class. Create an instance using new and then call the method of the instance.

Form1.foo will only work for static members of the Form class. Any normal member can only be accessed from a form instance.